# Как правильнее писать hasOne/hasMany?

Tags: php, yii2

Я пишу так:

```
/**
 * @return array|null|User
 */
public function getUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])->one();
}
```

А в примерах везде возвращают без `->one` только запрос. Аналогично и с hasMany (только там `->all()`). Как правильнее? Просто когда возвращаешь объект, а не запрос - можно за счет phpdoc подставить тайпхинты в IDE. Это очень удобно. Но с другой стороны порой приходится дублировать код когда в другом месте надо ту же связь, но с изменением запроса (например условие добавить). Правда редко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писать можно и так и так. В классе BaseActiveRecord переопределен __get, когда вы обращаетесь к $model->user обрабатывается такой кусок кода:

```
...
$value = parent::__get($name);
if ($value instanceof ActiveQueryInterface) {
    return $this->_related[$name] = $value->findFor($name, $this);
} else {
    return $value;
}
...
```

Из него видно что если вы в релейшене вернули запрос она его выполнит findFor, а если уже готовый результат, то просто вернет его.
Определеяется это по наличию интерфейса.

Как писать с точки зрения веры вам решать.